# PhpStorm "rsa key is corrupt or has the wrong version"

Tags: phpstorm, ssh-keys, openssh, phpstorm-2018.2

I'm using PhpStorm 2018.2 and attempting to connect to remote host using SSH key (I can connect via ssh on terminal).

When I enter the (newly created) rsa key into the remote host settings I get the error "'{path/to/key}_rsa' is corrupt or has unknown format" ... see image attached.

[image]

I have seen some bits about converting the key to an ssh2 key using this command

```
ssh-keygen -e -f ~/.ssh/key_rsa > ~/.ssh/key_rsa_ssh2
```

and using that in PhpStorm instead but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on @eugenemorozov's answer.  I had to do these 2 points.

- add the private key(s) to `ssh-agent` using `ssh-add` command;
  i did this by following [this](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) guide.
- choose OpenSSH Config and authentication agent authentication type option when configuring SFTP Deployment Connection options.

Answer (score 2):

The SSH library we use doesn't support these keys.
We're looking for solutions currently, as a workaround, please use ssh-agent and choose this authentication type in the Deployment Configuration.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24325

Comment: This dosn't really help.  What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to convert the key in puttygen, like this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-284623